# How to account for Research Time in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, agile

My team recently switched to using Team Foundation Server to support Agile. We decided to run sprints every two weeks. We plan to write the stories so, ideally, they can be finished at the end of each two week sprint. We find that some stories have tasks (usually research or learning someone elses API) that will take much longer than our sprint duration. Does TFS have some way to record effort into such tasks without making it look like the stories should be completed at the end of the current sprint? Failing TFS, is there some 'Agile' way of handling these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you figure out how to break down the work into smaller pieces.  My rule of thumb is a Task should be more than an hour and less than a day.

Alternatively, you can still create Tasks against User Stories that aren't assigned to a Sprint if you choose to.  Although that doesn't feel very Agile to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My thought was to create a 'Permanent' user story for the 'research' tasks. It doesn't feel very agile to me either. If the story is 'Developer researches data apis' is that really a user story anymore? Alternatively if the story is 'Ongoing Research' with a task 'Developer researches data apis" and the task can be associated with more than one story. So, I guess I'll go with the latter...

Comment: Why would your research within a sprint not be a "Spike" user story?